# "Мы встретились в авто-сервисе" или "мы встретились на авто-сервисе"?

Tags: предлоги

По идее, "в сервисе" кажется правильным вариантом, поскольку подразумевает место внутри помещения, в то время как второй вариант интуитивно указывает место на крыше сервиса.

Если это так, то почему тогда правильно будет "холодильник стоит на кухне", а не "в кухне"?

Есть ли какие либо конкретные правила в русском языке, которые описывают данную дилемму?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rosenthal et al., № 199.3.2:

> В выражениях *на почте, на заводе, на фабрике, на стадионе* употребление предлога на объясняется тем, что первоначально понятия *«почта», «завод», «фабрика», «стадион»* не связывались с представлением о помещении или здании: почта когда-то была на почтовой станции, на которой содержали ямщиков и держали лошадей; завод, фабрика, стадион могли занимать открытую территорию и состоять из нескольких сооружений (ср.: *в мастерской, в цехе, в спортзале* связывалось с представлением о закрытом помещении). Употребляются сочетания: *на избирательном участке*, но: *в полицейском участке*, *на полевом стане*, но устарелое: *в военном стане*, *в агитпункте*, но: *на наблюдательном пункте*.

In other words, the rule is ad hoc, you should just learn the correct preposition in the edge cases.

Note that those two prepositions may be used interchangeably in some constructs, like *на / в кухне* which you have mentioned, and several others.

[This graph](http://goo.gl/Rhp5v) shows how the usage varied in time:

[image]

i. e. *в кухне* prevailed between 1860 and 1930; *на кухне* after that time.

Argots use non-standard prepositions in phrases like *на тюрьме, на больнице* etc.

Comment: Thе same is applicable to certain geographical locales. It is rarely when you can hear "в Украину", usually they say "на Украину". At the same time you would never hear "на Татарстан" - it is always "в Татарстан".

Answer (score 5):

`На кухне` и `в кухне` - это [два равноправных варианта](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search_answer/?s=%ED%E0+%EA%F3%F5%ED%E5).
`На` не всегда означает "сверху на", сравните:

> Работать на заводе, на фабрике, на предприятии.
>
> Быть на концерте, на уроке, на выставке.

Выражение `на авто-сервисе` звучит для меня необычно, я бы предпочёл `в авто-сервисе`, по аналогии с `в мастерской`, а `на авто-сервисе` образовано по аналогии с `на заводе, на фабрике`.

Вот вам ещё про кухню, Григорий Остер, из книги "Вредные советы":

Если вы по коридору

Мчитесь на велосипеде,

А навстречу вам из ванной

Вышел папа погулять,

Не сворачивайте `в кухню`,

`В кухне` — твёрдый холодильник.

Тормозите лучше в папу.

Папа мягкий. Он простит.

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется что "на автосервисе" - это скорее "на обслуживании в автосервисе" или "на территории авто-сервиса": "машина на авто-сервисе". "Мы встретились на автосервисе" - мы встретились, когда машины проходили обслуживание в автосервисе.

А "в автосервисе" это скорее "в помещении автосервиса", т.е. "мы встретились в автосервисе" - мы встретились в здании автосервиса.